# Merge and Print Distinct Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm learning about dictionaries and I'd like to clarify something.

Let's say I have two dicts: `d1 = {'id1' : '1', 'id2' : '2', 'id3' : '3', 'id4' : '4'}` and `d2 = {'fruit1': 'Apple', 'fruit2': 'Banana', 'fruit3': 'Strawberry', 'fruit4': 'Kiwi'}`. I'd like to create a new dictioanry `d3` with the following content:
`{ 1 : Apple, 2 : Banana, 3 : Strawberry, 4 : Kiwi}`.

I've read this post [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

What's the best way to create this new dictionary? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Use `dict` and `zip`:

- This will work as long as both `dicts` are aligned

  - Modern python `dict` order is **guaranteed** to be insertion order as of v3.7, but should also be the case for v3.6.
- The `values` of `d1` are `str` type, so when they are made into `keys` of `d3`, they will be `str`, not `int`.

```py
d1 = {'id1' : '1', 'id2' : '2', 'id3' : '3', 'id4' : '4'} 
d2 = {'fruit1': 'Apple', 'fruit2': 'Banana', 'fruit3': 'Strawberry', 'fruit4': 'Kiwi'}

d3 = dict(zip(d1.values(), d2.values()))

print(d3)

>>> {'1': 'Apple', '2': 'Banana', '3': 'Strawberry', '4': 'Kiwi'}
```

### If you want the `keys` to be `int` type:

- `map` `int` to the `d1.values()`

```py
d3 = dict(zip(map(int, d1.values()), d2.values()))

print(d3)

>>> {1: 'Apple', 2: 'Banana', 3: 'Strawberry', 4: 'Kiwi'}
```

Comment: As mentioned in this answer, this only works if the dicts are aligned. In some versions of python, there is no guarantee on the order of keys/values.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared